# How do I keep track of cards in hand with multiple lists in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5

I am having the code as below:

```
import cards

def build_rank_D(H):
    dictionary = {}
    for i in range(0,len(H)):
        card = H[i]
        dictionary[card.rank()] = card
    return dictionary
c1 = cards.Card(7,1)
c2 = cards.Card(2,1)
c3 = cards.Card(7,2)
c4 = cards.Card(7,3)
c5 = cards.Card(2,3)
c6 = cards.Card(7,4)
c7 = cards.Card(3,4)
c8 = cards.Card(1,2)
H1 = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7]
H2 = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c7,c8]
print(build_rank_D(H1))
```

the output of the current code is:

```
    "{2: 2h, 3: 3s, 7: 7s}"
```

when it should be:

```
    "{2:[2c,2h], 3:[3s], 7:[7c,7d,7h,7s]}"
```

Essentially, I am trying to make a Texas Hold'em poker game. 7 cards must be examined (2 in hand, 5 community cards on table). I want to create a function to keep track of the cards in a dictionary, but I cannot seem to understand why my code is not adding the other cards as a list, but skipping them and only filling in 1 per key.

btw: in `c1 = cards.Card(7,1)` and the rest, that means the card is a 7 of clubs. if it were `c1 = cards.Card(7,2)` , that means the card is a 7 of hearts. 3 is a diamond. 4 is a spade.

Comment: Forget about the cards or even the script. Play around with dictionaries in a separate script. This will make your example more focused and simple. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Why did you wipe your question for something that doesn't make sense?

Comment: I will reupload it in a couple of days. Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dictionary[card.rank()] = card` replaces whatever was in that slot with the new one. You don't want this. You want to preserve the value already there and then add the next card to it.

This happens because it doesn't care what was in `dictionary[card.rank()]` already, it just assigns it a new value. Since you want to store more than one thing in the same key, this ends up storing the last value for each rank in your dictionary, that's why you are seeing the higher value cards only in each rank.

When it doesn't have anything in it already, this is the right thing to do. But you need to check if it has anything and, if so, add another card to what it already has.

So first, you want to check: Does my hand already have something in it?
In python, we can check that with `if x in y:`, which will be true if we already have something in that rank. If so, we want to `append()` the new card, which simply adds it to the list we already have there. `else` we just add the new card, but there is a slight change here too: `[card]` says take the card and put it inside a list. The list is what we `append()` onto.

The full change:

```
if card.rank() in dictionary:
    dictionary[card.rank()].append(card)
else:
    dictionary[card.rank()] = [card]
```

Comment: Why is it replacing whatever was in the slot with the new one?

Comment: @PapaKiroo because it is what a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) does. It stores `<Key, Value>` pairs. If you keep assigning them `a[X] = Y` you are just overriding the `Y` associated to the `X` (a key-value pair `<X, Y>`). What you want to do, is make `Y` a list, and update `Y`.

Comment: I used your advice and created a list. Another issue has arisen: all of my cards are being placed for each key.  EX: `{2: [7c, 2c, 7d, 7h, 2h, 7s, 3s], 3: [7c, 2c, 7d, 7h, 2h, 7s, 3s],...}`

Comment: @PapaKiroo Normally, I'd make you work a bit more before completing the solution, but I'm heading to bed and I'm not going to leave you hanging. Good luck with the rest of your program, I hope my answer explains the why, not just the how.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what you have written here. Let's walk it through line by line

```
def build_rank_D(H):                   
    dictionary = {}                    # every time you call a func a dict is created
    for i in range(0,len(H)):          # traversing the H..
        card = H[i]                    # you are trying to fetch the element at ith index
        dictionary[card.rank()] = card # you have key with it
    return dictionary                  # you are returning it back
```

you know how dict are right ? for each distinct key it stores a value and when it gets new value to the same keys then it replaces it. This is the reason why you are getting `"{2: 2h, 3: 3s, 7: 7s}"` instead of `"{2:[2c,2h], 3:[3s], 7:[7c,7d,7h,7s]}"`

Now we know what the problem is so we will dicuss the solution..
I will give you some hints here now..
1) check if the key already exists in dict
2) if key exists then add to the value of that same key
3) if you didn't find the key then insert the element